# SignalR - Connections with register from multiple partial views?

Tags: signalr

I've got multiple partial views in a page, in which I use SignalR.

For the correct execution all partial views need to register with the hub using an ID.

I've implemented this using:

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () { <hubname>.register(<id>); });
```

When there's only one partial view present on the page, it works as designed. But once there are 2 or more only one of the register commands is executed. And therefor only one of the partial views works.

I would prefer it if I could keep the partial views self contained.

Answer (score 3):

dfowler answered my question on JabbR:

```
// --- outside of the user controls, e.g. on the container page ---
$(function() {
  window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start();
});

// --- in your other pages ---
$(function() {
    window.hubReady.done(function() {
        // call hub method
    });
});
```

Comment: you don't know the order of `$(function()` so this only works if  `window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start();` is executed at beginning